# Is there a way to get date& time when user synced data Jawbone UP Server?

Tags: jawbone

My company do integration of our product with Jawbone API.

I'm looking for the way to get date&time when user uploaded data to Jawbone UP server last time. I mean time when users sync it's data from wearable device&smartphone to Jawbone Server.
Can't find something like that in API Spec. The only Idea I have is to use Pub Sub notification date & time as indicator that user recently uploaded data to server. However I'm not sure that Pub Sub notifications being sent only in case of data upload. Please let me know if you have an ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PubSub is the best way. You can use the type field in the notification to determine what kind of data was just synced.

There is a list of all the possible Notification Types under **All notification events** on the [Pub Sub documentation](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/pubsub).

Comment: No problem. Up votes and accepting the answer are always appreciated. :-)